# How to connect points in datatable between them in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I took data from this site
[CO2 emission](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ankanhore545/carbon-dioxide-emissions-of-the-world)

Reshaping

```
df_reshaped <- data.frame(Countries = df$Country,                           
                          CO2 = c(df$X2018, df$X2017, df$X2016),
                          year = c(rep("X2018", nrow(newdf)),
                                    rep("X2017", nrow(newdf)),
                                    rep("X2016", nrow(newdf))))

# head(df_reshaped)

            Countries     CO2  year
1               China 9663.36 X2018
2       United States 4749.57 X2018
3 European Union (27) 2636.99 X2018
4               India 2400.25 X2018
5           Indonesia 1269.55 X2018
6               Japan 1074.08 X2018
```

If I try to vizualize data

```
ggplot(df_reshaped, aes(year, CO2, group=1, col = Countries)) +  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image: go out like this]

I need to connect line each country in correct way.

Comment: Hi, could you please share your data using `dput(df_reshaped)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: As you want lines by countries you have to use `group= Countries`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @stefan also mentioned in the comments, you should use `group = countries`. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(aes(year, CO2, group = Countries, col = Countries)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Output:

[image]